# Voice Search in android application

Tags: android

Ive been working on and application that uses voice search. I have implemented the voice detection system. What I want to do is, copy the string from the speech signal and put into a webview that searches google for the results. Basically the app should search google for what the user says by copying the message into google's search bar.

Comment: Isn't that feature already available to everyone with an android device via voice search?